# Regex match everything excluding hashtags that are separated by white space

Tags: regex, hashtag

In a string, I want to match everything that is not a hashtag so I can replace the matches with nothing. The match should include any possible single # symbols as well as any possible anchor links that you may find in a URL, like for example http:\www.abc.com#anchor. And these conditions are where I am struggling with.

So far, I was only able to match everything that is not an hashtag but I cannot include these possible anchor links. I am using this regex:

```
\s*(?<![\#\w\ß\Ä\Ü\Ö\ä\ö\ü\"\!\?\.\,\;\:\^\°\$\&\+\-\*\/\@\§\%\{\}\[\]\(\)])[\d\w\s.$&+,:;=?@|()<>\".°^*%!~§\ß\Ä\Ü\Ö\ä\ö\ü\-\/\/\[\]\}\\]+
```

And you can find an example here: https://regex101.com/r/o6EQ1B/4

There are two main parts to the regex:

1. `(?<![\#\w\ß\Ä\Ü\Ö\ä\ö\ü\"\!\?\.\,\;\:\^\°\$\&\+\-\*\/\@\§\%\{\}\[\]\(\)])`

This part is used to ignore all kinds of characters that may be used to form a hashtag. I need something like this because there may be some hashtags like this that are valid in my use case: #sprint(IPs:1)

2. `[\d\w\s.$&+,:;=?@|()<>\".°^*%!~§\ß\Ä\Ü\Ö\ä\ö\ü\-\/\/\[\]\}\\]`

This part is being used to match any possible character that is not part of a hashtag.

I am not very experienced with regex, so I am not even sure if what I am trying to achieve with a single regex is even possible. I also apologize in advance if the regex I wrote is too complicated, but at least I got it somewhat working for me.

**UPDATE:**

I think I could find a way to achive what I was seeking: https://regex101.com/r/3CWVUy/2

I will use this regex to strip out everything matched so I am left with the hashtags I am interested in. The key was in this part: `(?<=\w\#).*`.

Comment: You do not usually match anything but a substring with regex. The usual approach is to either `split` with regex or `replace`, e.g. with a `\s*#\S+` regex. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9EZoQb/1).

Answer (score 0):

The hashtag part (or fragment) of a URL is the last part and it's optional. Apparently you want to get rid of the rest of the url, keeping only the fragment including the # character, and for that you want to match everything that's before the hashtag, but I think the opposite makes more sense, that is, extracting the piece that you're interested in and ignoring the rest, so you just have to match from the # character (if found) to the end.
If you specifically want to use a regex for that you can do:

```
'http:\\www.abc.com#anchor'.match(/#.*/)
```

Alternatively, you can extract the substring from the # character to the end. I don't know what language you're using but this is an example in Javascript:

```
const url = 'http:\\www.abc.com#anchor';
let fragment = '';
const index = url.indexOf('#');
if (index >= 0) {
  fragment = url.substring(index);
}
```

Comment: Hi Issac, thank you for your answer. What I want is that this part on the anchor links matches in my code as well so I can replace it with nothing. I don't want to extract it from the URL I just want it to be ignored when I am searching for hashtags. Please check this example here: https://regex101.com/r/o6EQ1B/4

You will notice that the anchor link is also being left out of the match, which is what I am trying to avoid. I am matching everything that is not a real hashtag because I am using a Tableau regex function to match and replace with nothing. The regex flavor being used is PCRE2

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide some examples and what should be matched in your examples?

Comment: Hi Isaac, I think I already figured it out. I updated the question with this information. If you open this link https://regex101.com/r/3CWVUy/2 you will see that everything is getting matched except the actual hashtags that I want. I will then replace the matches with nothing, so I have only have the hashtags left in the string. This is what I was aiming for.